# Compare two directories for differences in regular files

Tags: perl, file, directory, compare

Need to compare two directories and check through every file in both directories for files of the same name, if the same name occurs you check to see if the files have the same content, if so print > file <. If the file has the same name but not the same content < file > If there is a file that's not in directory 2 but in directory 1 <<< file1, and likewise >>> file2 for a file in dir 2 but not dir 1. 
I have been having trouble, my code doesn't even compare when I test to see if the files are equal in name.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w 
use File::Basename;

@files1 = `/usr/bin/find $ARGV[0] -print`;
chop @files1;
@files2 = `/usr/bin/find $ARGV[1] -print`;
chop @files2;

here: 
for ($i=1; @files1 >= $i; $i++) {

    for ($x=1; @files2 >= $x; $x++) {

        $file1 = basename($files1[$i]); 
        $file2 = basename($files2[$x]); 

        if ($file1 eq $file2) {

            shift @files1;
            shift @files2;

            $result = `/usr/bin/diff -q $files1[$i] $files2[$x]`;
            chop $result;

            if ($result eq "Files $files1[$i] and $files2[$x] differ") { 

                print "< $file1 >\n";
                next here;
            } 
            else { 

                print "> $file1 <\n";
            }
        }
        else  { 

            if ( !-e "$files1[$i]/$file2") { print ">>> $file2\n";}
            unless ( -e "$files2[$x]/$file1") { print "<<< $file1\n";}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered comparing the md5sums of the files?

Comment: New to perl, could you explain?

Comment: I think what you really want here is `rsync -rv --dry-run src/ dest/`

Comment: Not entirely sure how I could implement that into my script, I can't do this on the command line, I need to have a script :/

Comment: If you just want to know if two files are the same or different, and don't need to display the details, `diff` is overkill -- use `cmp`.

Comment: Learning Perl should include learning about CPAN which has lots of useful modules. For the file comparison consider http://search.cpan.org/~ni-s/File-Compare-1.1001/Compare.pm which avoids the call of `diff`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this :

```
diff -aqr /dir1 /dir2
```

or :

```
#!/bin/bash

for f;
    for g; do
        [[ "$f" != "$g" ]] &&
            cmp &>/dev/null "$f" "$g" || echo "$f is different of $g"
    done
done
```

**USE this**

```
./script dir1/* dir2/*
```

Comment: How does the bash script work? Would it not compare files of different names?

Comment: I fixed the small error in the bash script (missing `do` after `for f;`) and tested by replacing `cmp &>/dev/null` with `echo`. It seems to compare every pair of non-matching files, including those in the same directory. It does not compare the files with themselves but instead echoes that they are different!